ldapsearch and objectsid=*-500 for administrator accounts
Is there a way I can run ldapsearch and ObjectSid=*-500 to get the administrator accounts or any other way?  I've tried this and if I run a search with the exact ObjectSid value then I get a value but the * does not return anything (not even the exact ObjectSid record).
Thanks for your help!
In ldapsearch:
I've tried running the ObjectSID= and this works.
I've tried running ObjectSID=*500 and ObjectSID=*-500 and this does not work.  How to get this working?

objectSid does not support substring match because it is not a string attribute in the first place – it's a binary attribute that only has a special matching rule to accept string searches, which works by converting the string SID to binary SID and then performing all comparisons against the binary form (and that of course can't be done with string wildcards).
One method for finding the account that has a RID of 500 would be to retrieve the objectSid attribute from the domain object in order to get the "domain SID" (which will be in binary form), convert it to text form (see sid_to_text()), then append the -500 RID to get the SID for the "Administrator" account, then you will be able to do an exact-match search for that.
(Of course, this will only find the built-in "Administrator" account – it will not find anyone else who has Domain Admin rights; that needs another search for the group that has the -512 RID.)

import io
import struct

def sid_to_text(buf):
    buf = io.BytesIO(buf)
    revision, = struct.unpack("B", buf.read(1))
    if revision != 1:
        raise ValueError("unsupported SID revision %d" % revision)
    n_sub, = struct.unpack("B", buf.read(1))
    auth_hi, = struct.unpack(">H", buf.read(2))
    auth_lo, = struct.unpack(">L", buf.read(4))
    subauth = struct.unpack("<" + "L" * n_sub, buf.read(4 * n_sub))
    sid = [revision, (auth_hi << 32) | auth_lo, *subauth]
    sid = ["S", *map(str, sid)]
    return "-".join(sid)

import dns.resolver
import ldap

def find_dcs(domain):
    res = dns.resolver.resolve("_ldap._tcp.%s" % domain, "SRV")
    return [str(rr.target).rstrip(".") for rr in res.rrset]

def fqdn_to_dn(domain):
    # hopefully escape_dn is not needed for valid domain names
    dn = ["DC=%s" % dc for dc in domain.strip(".").split(".")]
    return ",".join(dn)

domain = "ad.example.com"
servers = find_dcs(domain)
base_dn = fqdn_to_dn(domain)

conn = ldap.initialize("ldap://%s" % servers[0])
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, False)
#conn.sasl_gssapi_bind_s()
conn.sasl_non_interactive_bind_s("GSS-SPNEGO")

res = conn.search_ext_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_BASE, attrlist=["objectSid"])
for dn, attr in res:
    if dn:
        domain_sid = attr["objectSid"][0]
        break

domain_sid_s = sid_to_text(domain_sid)
badmin_sid_s = "%s-500" % domain_sid_s
dadmins_sid_s = "%s-512" % domain_sid_s

res = conn.search_ext_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                        "(objectSid=%s)" % badmin_sid_s)
for dn, attr in res:
    if dn:
        print("Found built-in Admin: %s" % dn)

res = conn.search_ext_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                        filterstr="(objectSid=%s)" % dadmins_sid_s)
for dn, attr in res:
    if dn:
        print("Found Admins group: %s" % dn)

